# How can i change control palette (2.3) to new 4.0.0 in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, palette

I started developing an application on api level 2.3 (2 years ago), now i change the targetSDKVersion to 14 because i'd like to update the look of application.

I set:
   project.properties --> Taget= android-14
   manifest
      android:minSdkVersion="14"
       android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
   Android layout version to rendering layout to 14

What did i forget ? What is need to done to change palette to new design?

http://shrani.si/f/z/UV/4jYnRT0n/old.jpg
from this to this
http://shrani.si/f/2B/72/1kzceaog/now.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I faced that problem dude.. [image]:D

Create one blank project then copy Values-11 and Value-14 Folders to your original project.

[image]

Comment: I copy but still the same

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked Value-11 style xml

Replace all...

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

and in Values-14 folder xml

Replace all..

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
        res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

and then clean your all project and let me know.

Comment: No changes, did you change something else tu ?

Answer (score 0):

Dude check in your MANIEFEST file `<application>` tag there is one property of that called `"android:Theme"` or if that not presend then write this line or present then replace with that `android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"` sample

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" > //This line will change
```

And make sure this line present in Your res->Values-> styles :

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"/>
```